# Need to save data while Formatting

Tags: boot, partitioning, backup, lamp, format

I generally create 5 Partitions(/, /boot, /opt, /home, Swap) to install Ubuntu 16.04.
I Want to save my data of **/home** and **/opt/lampp** while formatting again.
I do it now by taking backup in Other Disks.

Is there any other way to take backup in system without any other disk.

Is there any other way to take backup in system without any other disk while I am logged in my system with a bootable USB.

Comment: That depends on which risks you want to avoid by the backup. If you want to prevent data loss through a disk failure, you have to find some kind of external media to backup to, like USB disk, DVD-RW, 2nd disk, rsync to another server, etc.  If you only want to save your data before formatting, you can save them to another partition that your are sure will not be formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is no need to take backup in another disk.

I your case you have allocated a partition home. If you only erase and install existing Ubuntu (root partition) home will be untouched. so if you copy the files in home it will be safe.

Just select erase and install Ubuntu over existing Ubuntu.

After re installation, you can mount existing home partition as in the below article.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

For this you have should have same username.